# Are there any GUI equivalents of "Initctl"?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, services

Are there any GUI equivalent of **Initctl**,

I have tried  [`boot-up Manager`](https://launchpad.net/bum)

In short I was looking for some advanced GUI based daemon control tool.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are mentioning the [Boot-up Manager](https://launchpad.net/bum). What's wrong with it? I found it to be useful. It's packaged as [bum](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bum).

```
# Installation:
sudo apt-get install bum
# Running it:
sudo bum
```